# Adding Google Firebase dependency to Spring Boot (Maven) not working

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, kotlin, maven

I'm trying to implement the Firebase Realtime Database in my Spring Boot application written in Kotlin.

However, the version number has a red line under it with the following error:

> Dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1' not found
> Description : The version of the dependency, e.g. 3.2.1. In Maven 2, this can also be specified as a range of versions. Version : 3.0.0+

I've taken al look at both the Firebase documentation and the Maven repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin/9.1.1) and the version should be correct.

Code (all dependencies listed):

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.cdimascio</groupId>
            <artifactId>dotenv-kotlin</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>9.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: Which spring boot version do you use? Which Maven version do you use? Why do you manually define jackson-databind version? Why define manually quart version? Are those red lines in your IDE (which IDE and which version of it do you use) ? If so first try to build your project on plain command line ?

Comment: Version looks valid and seems reachable. Your local maven repo download might have failed. Go to your maven repo at repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-admin and delete the folder 9.1.1. Do a Maven >> Update project in IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. In your project files, right-click on pom.xml file, then click "Maven", then click "Reload Project". Worked for me